# How to create custom slider in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I want to change the slider value indicator to like below.

[image]

I am not able to get the idea of how to use a custom painter to create bubble.

Comment: https://github.com/Ali-Azmoud/flutter_xlider

Answer (score 3):

Create a custom [`RangeSliderValueIndicatorShape`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/RangeSliderValueIndicatorShape-class.html) by implementing it, and provide it to [`SliderThemeData`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderThemeData-class.html) of your [`SliderTheme`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/SliderTheme-class.html), which is having your `RangeSlider` as a child:

```
SliderTheme(
        data: SliderThemeData(
          rangeValueIndicatorShape: Your_Implemented_RangeSliderValueIndicatorShape(),
        ),
        child: RangeSlider(
            values: RangeValues(10, 100),
            onChanged: null
        ),
```